# Traefik on Kubernetes wrong Client IP on incoming connections

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am running Traefik on Kubernetes and I have create an Ingress with the following configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whitelist-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefix
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.10.10.10/32, 10.10.2.10/23"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-x-forwarded-for: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /endpoint
        backend:
          serviceName: endpoint-service
          servicePort: endpoint-port
---
```

When I do a POST on the above endpoint, Traefik logs that the incoming IP is 172.16.0.1 and so my whitelist is not triggered. 
Doing an ifconfig I see that IP belongs to Docker

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.26.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.26.255.255
```

How can I keep the original IP instead of the docker one?

EDIT

Traefik is exposed as LoadBalancer and the port is 443 over SSL

This is its yml configuration

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik
  annotations: {}
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    name: https
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  externalIPs:
  - <machine-ip>
---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: default
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: traefik-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: traefik-ingress
        name: traefik-ingress
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 35
      volumes:
        - name: proxy-certs
          secret:
            secretName: proxy-certs
        - name: traefik-configmap
          configMap:
            name: traefik-configmap
      containers:
      - image: traefik:1.7.6
        name: traefik-ingress
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 900Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 25m
            memory: 512Mi
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 2
          httpGet:
            path: /ping
            port: 80
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 2
          httpGet:
            path: /ping
            port: 80
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/ssl"
            name: "proxy-certs"
          - mountPath: "/config"
            name: "traefik-configmap"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        - name: dashboard
          containerPort: 8080
        args:
        - --logLevel=DEBUG
        - --configfile=/config/traefik.toml
---
```

As you can see here is the output of kubectl get svc

```
traefik                       LoadBalancer   10.100.116.42    <machine-ip>     80:30222/TCP,443:31578/TCP   <days-up>
```

Note that Traefik is running in a single node kubernetes cluster (master/worker on the same node).

Comment: You need to add more info, what kind of kubernetes deployment are you testing? which of the traeffik deployment  methods are you using ?

Comment: @mdaguete I added traefik's yml configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In LoadBalancer service type doc [ssl support on aws](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#ssl-support-on-aws) you can read the following statement:

> HTTP and HTTPS will select layer 7 proxying: the ELB will terminate
>   the connection with the user, parse headers and inject the
>   X-Forwarded-For header with the user’s IP address (pods will only see
>   the IP address of the ELB at the other end of its connection) when
>   forwarding requests.

So if you add the following annotation to you traeffik service:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
```

It should work with the `ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-x-forwarded-for: "true"` annotation present in your ingress config and the forwarded header is added by the aws loadbalancer.

Disclaimer: I have not tested that solution.

Regards.

Comment: I am not running kubernetes on aws but it is on a bare metal; I managed to install it by following this guide https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E88884/html/kubernetes_install_worker.html

Comment: So, you'll need some kind of loadbalancer before traeffik (ie haproxy) to add the `x-forwarded-for` header .As LoadBlancer Services expects this kind of service, as in awk, azure, gce, etc.

Comment: So I Need to provision a haproxy as a replicaset on kubernetes but what kind of kubernetes service should it be? Load Balancer?

Comment: I think thay would be easy to provision the loadbalancer outside kubernetes and loadbalance the traeffik ports on k8s nodes ( configuring traeffik with NodePort).